# proper arrangement in foreach

Tags: php, foreach

```
$random = rand(4, 23);
$range = range(1, $random );
```

HI.. guys 
I have a random range value here in foreach function i want to display with below 
rules.. my aim is to display like a square box

if i get range 1 to 3 it has to display table like this

```
1 2
3
```

if range from 1 to 6

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

if range from 1 to 19

```
1   2  3  4  5
6   7  8  9 10
11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19
```

Comment: What determines how many rows/columns you need to display?

Comment: So what's your question? Is this homework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get the ceil of the square root of the number of records, and then anytime you're at an index with a mod of that value that is equal to 0, start a new line.  Since you already have `$random` something like:

```
$dim = ceil(sqrt($random));

foreach ($range as $index => $number) {
    print $number;
    if (!(($index + 1) % $dim)) {
      print "\n";
    }
    else {
      print " ";
    }
}
```

May need some adjustment (I'm not in PHP mode atm) and also doesn't factor in the padding but that should be straightforward.